# "wasm-ld: error: Unknown file type: d000205.o" (wasm and external library)

Tags: c++, linker, libraries, webassembly

I have linked an external library with wasm and I get this error while using emcc, with the correct libraries included.
My question is very similar to this post, basically the same: [Unknow file type: basic_oarchive.o (boost and emscripten)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61557566/unknow-file-type-basic-oarchive-o-boost-and-emscripten)